# Activity events on startActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any event triggered on an activity when I call

```
startActivity("activity_id", myIntent);
```

If the Activity exists already.

I pass a parameter to the activity via

```
i.putExtra("someID", someSerializableObject );
```

and would like to call a method to refresh a WebView.

Right now, the call on startActivity brings the activity in the foreground but the webview does not display what i want.

Comment: Check this answer it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167

Comment: Android activity life cycle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the flags in your Intent and the settings in your manifest, your activity will be called with either `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()`.