# When does android activity finish starts

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

When we call `activity.finish()` will the next android life cycle method be executed?

1) Lets say user clicks on a button
`onUserInteraction()` we have called `activity.finish()` 
will the action dispatched to the `onClicked` listener of the button?

2) lets say `onStart()` we have called `activity.finish()` 
will `activity.OnResume()` be called?

Comment: If you don't get an answer, give it a try and let us know.  I'm curious as to what you'll find.

Answer (score 3):

When the Activity first time loads the events are called as below:

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

When you click the back button OR try to finish() the activity the events are called as below:

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

When you click on Phone button the Activity goes to the background & below events are called:

```
onPause()
onStop()
```

Exit the phone dialer & below events will be called:

```
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```

I hope its clear now, [for detail please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop/8516056#8516056).

Answer (score 1):

When activity.finish() is called following lifecycle methods are called for that activity

```
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

Activity instance will be destroyed