# track down android application gets minimized

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there anyway tracking down application gets minimized? If there is something please let me know cause I have to update my own application when application gets minimized. It would be better doing somewhere irrespective of any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a callback in activity called `onUserLeaveHint()`. It is called when activity gets left not by back press, but some interruption - home button or may be incoming call. Create a base class Activity which calls to an Application instanse for some action and derive from this abstract class.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking exactly for this

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get an indication that application is being minimized by overriding the onpause and onstop methods then on the basis of your requirements you can do some action there.
Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop/8516056#8516056) as well