# Index Out of Range error after adding an AsyncTask

Tags: android, indexing, progressdialog, outofrangeexception

So I had a thread that was taking care of some network stuff for the app behind the scenes, but for some reason the IDE kept thinking that I was updating the UI so it wouldn't stop crashing. I changed it over to an AsyncTask and now I get an Index Out of Range error. Before I had started working with threading the app worked fine, it just was really slow. I haven't changed any of the original code that worked I've just added to it with the threads. So I know that my original code isn't the issue it's the code that creates the AsyncTask or at least it should be that code. My code is shown below along with the errors:

**Main Java file**

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Shc_BalloonSat_Activity extends Activity
{
int historyCountFromUser;
httpAPI api;
mapAPI map;
runDialog dialog;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#####");
DecimalFormat decimalf = new DecimalFormat("##.######");
AlertDialog alert;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor prefEditor;
String lastpacketsPHP;


// User to determine how many packet the user would like to see.
int userDefinedCount = 5;

/*
 *  Called when the activity is first created. 
*/

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadApp();
}

public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }

    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public void showAlert()
{
    alert.setTitle("Sorry!");
    alert.setMessage("Please connect to the internet to access the full functionality of this app.");
    alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {

        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

/*  public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    loadApp();
}

public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    loadApp();
}*/

public void loadApp()
{
    setContentView(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.layout.main);
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    String returned = "";
    lastpacketsPHP = "";
    pref = getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", 0);
    prefEditor = pref.edit();
    prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* PHP file URL goes here */");
    prefEditor.commit();

    // These next two lines are used to test the PHP files on the SHC server by determining if PHP is set up correctly.
    //prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "/* PHP file URL goes here */");
    //prefEditor.commit();   

    if (!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
    showAlert();
    }

    else
    {
    api = new httpAPI(this);
        map = new mapAPI(this);
        dialog = new runDialog();

        try
        {
            returned = api.getData();
        }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Unable to receive data at this time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

        TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.info);
    infoTV.setText(returned);
    assignInfoToInfoTextView();
    assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
    submenu.add(0, 5, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 5 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, 10, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 10 Packets");
    submenu.add(0, 20, Menu.NONE, "Get Last 20 Packets");
    inflater.inflate(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.menu.mainmenu, submenu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.viewKML:
            viewKML();
            return true;
        case 5:
            viewLast5Packets();
            return true;
        case 10:
            viewLast10Packets();
            return true;
        case 20:
            viewLast20Packets();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void assignInfoToInfoTextView()
{
    TextView infoTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.info);

    try
    {
        String result = api.result.substring(1, api.result.length()-2);
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);

    double altitudeData = json_data.getDouble("altitude");
    double altitudeInFeet = altitudeData * 3.281;
    String infoText = "Last Known Altitude: " + df.format(altitudeInFeet) + " ft\n";

    Double speedData = json_data.optDouble("speed");

    if (speedData.isNaN())
    {
        speedData = 0.00;
    }

    Double direction = json_data.optDouble("heading");
    String directionUnits = " degrees from N";
        String directionText = "";

        if (direction == 0)
        {
            directionText = ", N";
        }
        else if (direction > 0 && direction < 45)
        {
            directionText = ", N NE";
        }

        else if (direction == 45)
        {
            directionText = ", NE";
        }

        else if (direction > 45 && direction < 90)
        {
            directionText = ", E NE";
        }

        else if (direction == 90)
        {
            directionText = ", E";
        }

        else if (direction > 90 && direction < 135)
        {
            directionText = ", E SE";
        }

        else if (direction == 135)
        {
            directionText = ", SE";
        }

        else if (direction > 135 && direction < 180)
        {
            directionText = ", S SE";
        }

        else if (direction == 180)
        {
            directionText = ", S";
        }

        else if (direction > 180 && direction < 225)
        {
            directionText = ", S SW";
        }

        else if (direction == 225)
        {
            directionText = ", SW";
        }

        else if (direction > 225 && direction < 270)
        {
            directionText = ", W SW";
        }

        else if (direction == 270)
        {
            directionText = ", W";
        }

        else if (direction > 270 && direction < 315)
        {
            directionText = ", W NW";
        }

        else if (direction == 315)
        {
            directionText = ", NW";
        }

        else if (direction > 315 && direction < 360)
        {
            directionText = ", N NW";
        }

        else if (direction.isNaN())
        {
        directionText = " Invalid direction";
        }

        else
            {

            }

        infoText += "Last Known Velocity: " + df.format(speedData) + " m/s " + direction + directionUnits + directionText + "\n";

    double recentLatitudeData = json_data.getDouble("latitude");
    infoText += "Last Known Latitude: " + df.format(recentLatitudeData) + "\n";

    double recentLongitudeData = json_data.getDouble("longitude");
    infoText += "Last Known Longtitude: " + df.format(recentLongitudeData) + "\n";

    infoTV.setText(infoText);
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("<tag>", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error in (Last Known) method!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("<tag>", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error in (Last Known) method!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void assignInfoToHistoryTextView()
{

    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(api.result);
        TextView historyTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(shc_BalloonSat.namespace.R.id.history);

        for (int count = 1; count < userDefinedCount; count++)
        {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(count);

                double altitudeData = json_data.getDouble("altitude");
                double altitudeInFeet = altitudeData * 3.281;
                String historyText = "Altitude: " + decimalf.format(altitudeInFeet) + " ft\n";

                Double speedData = json_data.optDouble("speed");

                if (speedData.isNaN())
                {
                    speedData = 0.00;
                }

                    Double direction = json_data.optDouble("heading");
                    String directionUnits = " degrees from N";
            String directionText = "";

            if (direction == 0)
            {
                directionText = ", N";
            }
            else if (direction > 0 && direction < 45)
            {
                directionText = ", N NE";
            }

            else if (direction == 45)
            {
                directionText = ", NE";
            }

            else if (direction > 45 && direction < 90)
            {
                directionText = ", E NE";
            }

            else if (direction == 90)
            {
                directionText = ", E";
            }

            else if (direction > 90 && direction < 135)
            {
                directionText = ", E SE";
            }

            else if (direction == 135)
            {
                directionText = ", SE";
            }

            else if (direction > 135 && direction < 180)
            {
                directionText = ", S SE";
            }

            else if (direction == 180)
            {
                directionText = ", S";
            }

            else if (direction > 180 && direction < 225)
            {
                directionText = ", S SW";
            }

            else if (direction == 225)
            {
                directionText = ", SW";
            }

            else if (direction > 225 && direction < 270)
            {
                directionText = ", W SW";
            }

            else if (direction == 270)
            {
                directionText = ", W";
            }

            else if (direction > 270 && direction < 315)
            {
                directionText = ", W NW";
            }

            else if (direction == 315)
            {
                directionText = ", NW";
            }

            else if (direction > 315 && direction < 360)
            {
                directionText = ", N NW";
            }

            else if (direction.isNaN())
            {
                directionText = " Invalid direction";
            }

            else
            {

            }

            if (direction.isNaN())
            {
                historyText += "Velocity: " + df.format(speedData) + " m/s " + directionText + "\n";
            }

            else
            {
                historyText += "Velocity: " + df.format(speedData) + " m/s,\n" + direction + directionUnits + directionText + "\n";
            }

                double latitudeData = json_data.getDouble("latitude");
                historyText += "Latitude: " + df.format(latitudeData) + "\n";

                double longitudeData = json_data.getDouble("longitude");
                historyText += "Longtitude: " + df.format(longitudeData) + "\n\n";

                historyTV.setText(historyText);
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data: " + e.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data: " + e.toString());
    }

}

void viewLast5Packets()
{
    if (!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        showAlert();
    }

    else
    {
        userDefinedCount = 5;
        prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://space.uah.edu/balloonsat_app/get_last_5_BS_packets.php");
        prefEditor.commit();
        assignInfoToInfoTextView();
        assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
    }
}

void viewLast10Packets()
{
    if (!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        showAlert();
    }

    else
    {
        userDefinedCount = 10;
        prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://space.uah.edu/balloonsat_app/get_last_10_BS_packets.php");
        prefEditor.commit();
        assignInfoToInfoTextView();
        assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
    }
}

void viewLast20Packets()
{
    if (!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        showAlert();
    }

    else
    {
        userDefinedCount = 20;
        prefEditor.putString(lastpacketsPHP, "http://space.uah.edu/balloonsat_app/get_last_20_BS_packets.php");
        prefEditor.commit();
        assignInfoToInfoTextView();
        assignInfoToHistoryTextView();
    }
}

public void viewKML()
{
    if (!isNetworkConnected(this))
    {
        showAlert();
    }

    else
    {
        map.openKML();
    }
}
}
```

**httpAPI.java**

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.util.Log;

public class httpAPI
{
Shc_BalloonSat_Activity shc;
HttpClient client;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
InputStream is;
String result = "";
HttpPost httppost;

 public httpAPI(Shc_BalloonSat_Activity aContext)
 {
        shc = aContext;
 }

public String getData() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    httppost = new HttpPost(shc.pref.getString(shc.lastpacketsPHP, shc.lastpacketsPHP.toString()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    response = client.execute(httppost);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in HTTP connection: " + e.toString());
    }

    try
    {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: " + e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

**runDialog.java**

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class runDialog extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
Shc_BalloonSat_Activity shc;
httpAPI api;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public void onPreExecute()
{
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(shc);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++)
{
    publishProgress(5);

    try
    {
    api.getData();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

progressDialog.dismiss();
return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
{
progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute()
{

}
}
```

**Errors:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Index 5 out of range [0..5)
```

I get this error each time it tries to get the data from the URL. I can also email the apk file to anyone who would like to see what it's actually doing. I also have reason to believe that what ever the cause of this is might also be causing my ProgressDialog to not show up. Any ideas on why I could be getting this error?

Comment: I don't see call to runDialog in your main activity, also please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle , seems like loadApp() will be called twice most of the time which you probably don't want.

Comment: I believe you are correct on the loadApp() being called more than once. From what I just read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop From what I understood in that thread it will be called more than once. Also I called runDialog in my else statement like I did the other classes. I've updated my code to match what it is now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out that I was passing an activity, not calling the ProgressDialog correctly, and set up my AsyncTask incorrectly. Thank goodness I found someone who had the time to sort debug my project for me.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Can you tell me what exact changes did you make in your code ?