# Android Activity - OnStop() triggers

Tags: android, android-activity

I am facing an issue with activity lifecycle. Here is the scenario

Activity 1 > Activity 2 > Activity 3

**Navigate from Activity1 to Activity2** > OnPause() of Activity1 called (correct)

**Navigate from Activity2 to Activity3** > Here OnStop() of Activity1 called (**incorrect** - It should happen in first step)

**Navigate back to Activity2 from Activity3** > Again OnStart() of Activity1 called (incorrect - but I know it happens because of OnStop())

I am wondering how this happens? Any thoughts please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963381/android-activity-lifecycle-state-order-when-new-activity-starts

Answer (score 0):

I think on second activity you are calling on finish() method that's why on Stop() method is calling. If you don't want to launch your activity1 again then make your activity single task in manifest file. Correct me if understood wrong.