# Android onClose event

Tags: android, events

I want to show a "Thanks for using" message when the application close.

What is the event that handles application closing?

Comment: @user1479606 No - Just got it too late.

Comment: Please refer to this post on Android activity life cycle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose Your activities are in such as A->B->C->D. When user press back button from D activity  then goes to C then press back button from C Activity he will go to B activity again press back button user will comes on A Launcer Activity. So on press back button you can give message to user.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Thanks for using application!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()l
    finish();
    return;
}
```

or

When press direct home key from any activity for that you need to

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

After overriding above method, now you can easily listen HOME Key press in your activity using onKeyDown() method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       Toast.makeText(context,"Thanks for using application!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

you can use `onDestroy()` or `onBackPressed()` callbacks on your main/launcher activity

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the dialog to display only when the app is completely closed(removed from background as well), You could just override `onDestroy()` method in your first activity.