# Starting main Activity every time

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

I am having an issue with my app that is i need to call `splashActivity` i.e. main `Activity` every time when user launches an app by pressing  the recent app button in the device  when user has exit from the app by clicking `back` / `home` buttons.
Is there anything i can do to make the things work.I tried using flag `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` but this is not working too.

Comment: don't. splashscreens are evil and go against proper application flow.

Comment: @njzk  But i really want the flow because from splashscreen i have to call appropriate activity.

Comment: You should probably look into your [Activity LifeCycle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/1134705).

Comment: post your manifest. `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` should do what you want.

Comment: @DavidWasser this is not working

Comment: Like I said, please post your manifest. There's something strange here. We can help if you give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

as interesting
When you kill process and your app visible (you see  pages, not pressed home buttons)
your app be restarted

first you need this source

```
moveTaskToBack(true);  (in you MAIN page)
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

or

go in you MAIN page

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), [MAIN].class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

and in your main class

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Comment: yes , you right, or how restart program..? if i understand you need destroy activity?