# Android Populating items from SQLite into listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am just starting android and I have a quick question with sqlite db.

i created a db with a couple of columns but am now withdrawing just one column from that. I was wondering if I should withdraw that column into an array of strings, then populate it into a listview, or directly put it into an adapter of sorts (which i am starting to read about).

also, if i open up a new activity, and change the information of some item (deleting or inserting), then go back to this same activity, would it automatically update or would i have to override onstart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way of populating the UI from a DB in Android is with a `CursorLoader`. try reading the [dev-guide here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

basically, you implement the `LoaderManager.Callbacks`, and in the `onCreate`, query the DB and pass the response to the loader.

Comment: Thanks, im building a cursorloader and in all the examples i only see a fragmentactivity used and not an activity. I was wondering why that is

Comment: don't worry about it, It can be in all activities

Comment: okay so i have 2 peices of code and i don't know why one does what it does                                                                         public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
      //not too sure what's going on here
      String[] projection = new String[]     {db.retColName("KEY_TITLE"), db.retColName("KEY_ID")};
  
      CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(
        this,
        DBHandler, 
        projection, 
        null, 
        null,
        null);
  
      return loader;

     } //if i don't use a content provider how can i finish it?

Comment: @EternalFalls, there is no formatting option in comments, this could be a new question

Answer (score 0):

First call a function from db that returns a Cursor

```
 Cursor cursor = dbhelper.Function();
```

Then use an array of string

```
String [] from = new String [] {
        Dbadapter.KEY_NAME
}
```

And then use an array of int to assign it

```
  Int []  to = new int []  {
        R.id.textview1
 }
```

Then Set adapter

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter ( this, R.layout.listview, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

Answer (score -3):

Its best to override onResume() for that, as every time you update and come back to your app onResume() gets a callback( refer [Android life cycle activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947587/android-life-cycle-activities)). Here only you can fetch the record of that column and inflate it on the list.

Welcome to Android development! All the best!

Comment: this is a terrible answer that represents all that you should stay away from.
managing your own cursor is bad, and should be avoided