# List Items disappears when device is on wake off state

Tags: android, android-listview, android-lifecycle

I am stuck with a problem since 1 week. I have made a custom list view. The items are add in the list view on a button click. All the items are display normally in the list view. But after 10 seconds when the device light is switched off and swipe the screen, the items in the `ListView` disappear. My list view in xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvEditItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSelectToEdit"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

My activity file is :-

```
ListView mView;
mView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvEditItem);
mView.setDivider(null);
mView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

private View lastSelectedView = null;

public void clearSelection()
{
    if(lastSelectedView != null)
       lastSelectedView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
   clearSelection();
   lastSelectedView = view;
   view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightGreen);

   String items=arrayList.get(position).toString();
   String s[]=items.split("~");

   System.out.println("value of Array>>>>>>>=="+s.length);

   tvGender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvSubCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvStyle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvColor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   tvGender.setText(s[0]);
   GenderData.gender=s[0];
   tvGender.setTypeface(face);

   tvCategory.setText(s[1]);
   CategoryData.category=s[1];
   tvCategory.setTypeface(face);

   tvSubCategory.setText(s[2]);
   SubCategoryData.subCategory=s[2];
   tvSubCategory.setTypeface(face);

   brand.setText(s[3]);

   tvStyle.setText(s[4]);
   StyleData.style=s[4];
   tvStyle.setTypeface(face);

   tvSize.setText(s[5]);
   SizeData.size=s[5];
   tvSize.setTypeface(face);

   tvColor.setText(s[6]);
   ColorData.color=s[6];
   tvColor.setTypeface(face);

   String as=s[7].replace("$", "");
   price.setText(as);

   originalRetailer.setText(s[8]);

   originalLink.setText(s[9]);
});
```

and My Adapter class is:-

```
public class CustomEditListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
ArrayList<String> mArrayList;
ArrayList<String> mshowItemsOnListView;
Typeface face;
public CustomEditListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> mArrayList,ArrayList<String> mshowItemsOnListView ) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mArrayList=mArrayList;
    this.mshowItemsOnListView=mshowItemsOnListView;
    face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "tahoma.ttf");
     System.out.println("Final ArrayList which has to be post>>>"+mArrayList.toString());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return ConcatData.mSet.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
   return mshowItemsOnListView.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder;


   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_select_item_view, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      holder.txtName.setTypeface(face);

      convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   // holder.txtName.setText(mArrayList.get(position));
   holder.txtName.setText(mshowItemsOnListView.get(position));
   return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
   TextView txtName;
}
}
```

The custom_select_item_view.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/list_arrow_my_item_box"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
         android:padding="5dip"
         />
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It is problably due to the activity life-cycle, see [Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for) for more information.

In short, if you application is suspended or paused, its resources are shredded and rebuild when the application is resumed again.

In this process your list of added items is destroyed and rebuild. While rebuilding the added items also need to be (explicitly) restored as well! So keep them store the item information in a 'secure' location so you are able to rebuild the list items using this stored information.

For more information how to do so, check the Android documentation on [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).