# Back button finishes parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have some problems with the default Android lifecyle.

My app has an `Activity` (let's call it `A`) and a `MapActivity` (let's call it `M`)

Activity `A` has an `AsyncTask` to retrieve an image from an URL (EDIT3: which seems to not affect my issue, but I mention it in order to give full info)
and the MapActivity `M` is currently an empty map, no config or modifications made.

My use case is the folowing:

I go through my app normally, and end up starting `A` with no errors.
When I start `M` from `A` everything works as expected, but when I go back, Activity `A` is already finished.

I `Log.d` every step in the lifecycle in both activities and found the following:

Start Activity `A`

```
onCreate  - A
onStart   - A
onResume  - A
```

Start Activity `M`

```
onPause   - A
onCreate  - M
onStart   - M
onResume  - M
onStop    - A
```

Back on Activity `M`

```
onPause   - M
onDestroy - A
onStop    - M
onDestroy - M
```

So I end up finishing Activity `A` and `M` when I press the back button on `M`

I tried different kind of Activities (MapActivities, Activities, from the same package, from different packages) with the same exact result.

EDIT:

- I don't use `finish();` method anywhere
- My activity is started with the folowing code:

`Intent I = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);`
`context.startActivity(I);`

EDIT2:

- Checked [isFinishing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) method on the Activity `A` `onPause` step, and the result is `false` so it was not suposed to be finishing

Any idea? is there something I am missing?
Thx in advance for your time and ideas!

Comment: Do you use some launchModes for activities or intent flags?

Comment: are you calling `finish();` on `A` ?

Comment: Nope I don't use either `finish();` nor flags. This information is now on the question post, thanks!

Comment: Are you overriding onBackPressed() method in your activities?

Comment: Nope in any of them. That's why I'm so surprised this behaviour is happening...

Comment: Try to take out your AsyncTask and see if everything works :)

Comment: I tried, same results. I specified there was an `AsyncTask`in order to give full info, but apparently it doesn't affect my issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167

Comment: You might also check if activity `A` is not launched as a `singleInstance` (u can check it in your manifest), that shouldn't be this, but I guess it's still worth checking just in case ;)

Comment: Eureka! thx @Stigi it was not this exact property but your answer was totally on the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stigi who pointed me in the right path to keep debugging. (Can I give you points somehow?)

In my case `android:noHistory="true"` was set on the `Manifest.xml` so when I came back from Activity `M` to `A`it was not on the pile, and it looked like it was closed.

Comment: hehe I guess there is no way to give me any points, but I'm still glad to help :) btw accept ur own answer, so others will see how to solve similar issue, cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

While going from Activity `M` to Activity `A`, make sure you don't use `finish();` since it removes the current activity from the stack.