# Which activity life cycle methods are called when Camera intent is started?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Can someone please lists all the activitie's and fragment's life cycle methods which will be called?

I have one activity, that activity has one fragment.

Lets assume that application is running. From fragment I start camera intent. `getActivity().startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, ConstantClass.CAMERA_REQUEST);` (please notice that I call **my activite's** startActivityForResult method).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for/8516056#8516056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Activity LifeCycle**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

**Fragment LifeCycle**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Instead of posting images of the lifecycle, look at these links that are in the docs. They show the lifecycles which activities and fragments will always follow even if you are using `startActivityForResult()`. Which exact branch your `Activity` will take is going to depend on what else you do inside of it like like if you call any lifecycle methods. Basically if you can still see some of the original `Activity` then `onPause()` will be called such as with a `Dialog` or using transparency. If it occupies the whole screen then `onStop()` would be called.

Other factors could change the direction also. If this isn't what you want to know then you will need to be a little more specific with your question if it appears to be doing something that you don't think it should.