# Android: Activity LifeCycle

Tags: android, database, android-activity, destroy

I'm learning about android programming from official website(http://developer.android.com).
I understand most of life cycle, but I'm not sure when system is destroying activity.

From what I understand, system is destroying activity when some activity stays for longer time in `onStop()` or when foreground activity needs more resources. Is that right ?

And from what I read the most efficient way to update data base is in `onStop()`, but let's say user is adding one word to my 'dictionary' application. So I need to gather this words in list and then update data base? Or I should insert rows  to DB with each word ( in other method ) ?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better? You want to know if you should add the word to the DB when the user adds it or just add all the words in onStop()?

Comment: User fills input field with one word and confirms it. My question:  the database should be updated in this moment? Right after confirm or I should gather all words somewhere and wait until onStop() ? I hope it's clear now.

Comment: It seems to be a very simple, fast DB operation so I think you can add it right away, when the user adds it. Ideally, you would do such thing in a separate thread, however.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for/8516056#8516056

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you will never know when android force your application to stop.

So it is like this

onCreate() // here you could initialize

This is safe

onResume() // here turn on

onPause() // here turn off

// After this it is not sure

But if you are sure that finish() is always called you could use others

Answer (score 0):

Data has to be persisted in the `onPause()`method. Otherwise, the system might terminate your process without further notice.