# which method is called in current activity when moving to another activity?

Tags: android

which `method` is called in `current activity` when moving to another `activity`? Let's take i am in `Activity A`, from A i move to `Activity B`.

I want to execute a particular `piece of code` while moving to `Activity B`

Comment: you should atleast read activity life cylcle , just google it and you will get your answer.

Comment: When you navigate from activity A to B. Activity A is paused. So onPause() is called

Comment: You need to learn Activity Life cycle ,check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is called on your current activity *specifically* for "moving to another activity".

Your current activity will be called with `onPause()` when it leaves the foreground from an input standpoint, and it will be called with `onStop()` when it is no longer visible. However, those will be called for any trigger for those events, including the user pressing HOME or BACK.

Comment: When I move from one say activity A to B. will A's onStop will be called first or B's onCreate?

Comment: @dirtydexter: I do not know, and I would not count on that behavior remaining consistent over time.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code inside Activity B's `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

onPause and probably onStop (if the new activity takes up the entire screen) will be called on A. onDestroy 'can' be called at this point, but the system will keep it alive if it can.

onCreate, onStart, onResume will be called on B, unless B is already in the stack and you either use some flags in the intent, or B has a special launchMode, in which case, rather than onCreate, onNewIntent will be called.

Answer (score 1):

`onPause()` method is calledwhen it leaves the foreground and `onStop()` method is called when the activity is no longer visible.. Also refer to the complete activity life cycle in the below mentioned link

Refer to table 1 of the activity life cycle in this link [Activity Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

onPause() and then onStop() methods will call when you change the activity ,,if you finish the current activity while moving to the second activity the onDestory() also called..

**Here is an intrusting issue that if you start an your new activity in onStop method the onPause and onStop method wont call again :)**