# Some problems about Oncreate of Application and Activity in Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, oncreate, android-launcher

I have already written some Android application, but recently I find that I still not really know how an Android Application works. My problems are something about the AndroidManifest.xml, I want to know something about the life cycle of Android applications. 
In the AndroidManifest.xml, there is an Application label and there is a sub-label of activity. In the activity label, main activity of the application will be marked like this:

```
<activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.sofesec.mainactivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This means that the class called "com.sofesec.mainactivity" is the main activity of the application, and it will get executed first. 
But there is a field called "android: name" in the label of application -- the parent lable of activity -- and the value of the field may be "com.sofesec.lcz.test". When the application starts, the "com.softsec.lcz.test" class will be executed as well.
I don't know which class is executed first. This is something about life cycle of an android application. Thanks for giving me some help !

This is the code of my application here:

```
public class test extends Application {
    private final String TAG = "test";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OriginalApplication oa = new OriginalApplication(this);
        oa.configApplicationEnv();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use below link to know in detail about activity life cycle and manifest file.

[Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I know the life cycle of activity, but I don't  know the life cycle of application. For example, in the application, the function onCreate() can also be Overrided and the function will be executed. I don't know the two onCreate function, in application and in activity. Thanks!

Comment: I thinks you have not seen the post given by Yaqub Ahmad which described how the life cycle works in application,he has used the log to see it in details.

Comment: I think the example show the life cycle of the activity, instead of the application.