# Up button for low level activities works automatically, why? (setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled)

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working through Android programming tutorials and am trying to learn ["Up" navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html).  I got it to work by adding setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled, but when I remove this statement, clean the project and re-deploy, up navigation still works.  Why does this happen?  I should just see a static, go-nowhere child activity screen, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

Activities are automatically pushed onto a stack, the up/back button naturally pops the stack.
[Life cycle of Android Activity after pressing Back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011751/life-cycle-of-android-activity-after-pressing-back-button)