# Android Pager using Fragment

Tags: android

In android Coding I have some doubts.I am working In Paging concepts. 
        I have two Fragments. One is Master Fragment and another one is Transaction Fragment.
        In master one Button is available. That is vendor. If we click the vendor button we can create a new vendor details.
        Its work fine to move forward. That is if we click the vendor button the next page is opened. But if return backward by pressing it doesn't work.
        By pressing the back button from new vendor creation to vendor it works. But if we press back button from vendor to Pager fragment it does n't work. 
        Here I have attached the coding and screen shots. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Screen Shots

---

[Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRUUu.png)
[Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V3Kb.png)
[Vendor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLHe3.png)
[Vendor Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLJiu.png)
The following is the code when we click the backbutton

```
Fragment fragment = new MainActivity();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frag_act_cont, fragment, "Class Name").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understand your question. Have a look at the Android Developer Page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments)

To be able to provide proper back navigation you have to add the fragment to the back stack by

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       // Add this transaction to the back stack
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button the onBackPressed method is called that causes activity to finish.Have a look at this post:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011751/life-cycle-of-android-activity-after-pressing-back-button`

and try this piece of code.On your backpress method do something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_act_cont, "Class Name").commit();
    }
```