# Manipulate the checkbox state in Android lifecycle

Tags: android, checkbox, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my application, my requirement is like I want checkbox to be checked for first time at the time of opening the app and after that I want that value to be retained till the app is unistalled from the device.

For this purpose I have used "Shared Preferences" to store the value on first time check. Till this point everything is fine.

When I press the "home" button and again accessing the app checkbox is in unchecked state. Now for this I have written code to check the checkbox in `onResume`, but when I close the apps in my system and reopen the app again checkbox is resetting to `unchecked`. I am not sure how to solve this.

I read the lifecycle of Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for).

After reading this I am assuming to write the checked code in `onRestart` but again not sure whether the approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using the shared preferences... Initially I have declared the shared preferences wrong now code was working and also I have used `onResume` to reinitate the checked value.