# How to stop audiotrack and audiorecord playback on back press in android?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-audiorecord, audiotrack

I have an `Activity` A and `Activity` B.

In `Activity` A audio record and playback performs and on the press of back button audiotrack and audio record stops without any issue, but the main problem is in `Activity` B there is a video,when the footage of the video ends it moves back to `Activity` A.

Now the issue is at this time when I press back button the voice playback starts, means audiotrack and audiorecord doesn't stops.

I have gone through activity life cycle but i didn't got the desired `Activity`.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    startActivity(intent); 
    m_aboutOnyx.stop(); 
    timer.cancel(); 
    if(c_b_left == 1 || c_b_Right == 1 || c_b_fart ==1 || c_b_transperant ==1 ||c_b_food ==1 ||c_b_thunder ==1 || c_b_thumbs_up ==1){ 
        timer1.cancel();     
    } 
    isRecording = false; 
    track.stop(); 
    track.release(); 
    record.stop(); 
    record.release(); 
    this.finish(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will be called when you click the back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

   // Call your function to stop the audio recording here.
}
```

If you want to stop the audio recording when your activity goes to background, then :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   // Call your function to stop the recordinhg here.

}
```

For more activity [lifecycle functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/2219600)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: but I am not using media player.

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
  
  super.onBackPressed();
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     startActivity(intent);
  m_aboutOnyx.stop();
  timer.cancel();
  if(c_b_left == 1 || c_b_Right == 1 || c_b_fart ==1 || c_b_transperant ==1 ||c_b_food ==1 ||c_b_thunder ==1 || c_b_thumbs_up ==1){
   timer1.cancel(); 
  }
  isRecording = false;
  track.stop();
  track.release();
  record.stop();
  record.release();
         this.finish();
      }