# Usage of onPause, onResume , onStop when declaring min-sdk

Tags: android

I'm developing a very Simple App. I tested my App in various devices. It works fine. But I do not use OnPause or onStop or onResume methods. because my app running well and resume and stop well without any crash. ... Is these methods useless for simple apps like mine? or I'm wrong? or it is because I declared min-sdk 11?

Comment: If you are not using, you can simply remove it...no need to override it..

Comment: if there is no any problem then there is not mandotry to override activity all or any method.

Comment: Here is explanation of Activity LifeCycle
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

those are Activity life-cycle callback functions means that they will trigger even you are not using/overriding them and they are not related to min SDK.

you can find very useful information here:

[Activity Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

The use of different Activity life-cycle methods is already discussed in below Link.
[Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for)

Here, you can find good discussion about these life-cycle methods of Activities.

Check in your application if you need to override any of them. 
For more comprehensive details of Activity life-cycle, refer [Activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)