# which method run first after calling an activity with startActivityForResult() method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activity's and want to send an id to the second one.
in second activity i want to read some requirement`s data from db (such as some config data for example).
i want to know what method of my second activity call first and its guaranteed that run?

Comment: I didnt understand last line of your question. Can plz share some more detail?

Comment: i want to know in which method of my second activity i must call my r/w data from db function`s ?

Comment: onCreate ? onStart ? onResume ? or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very first method that will be called is onCreate() method.

for getting data from intent:
1) in your 1st activity:

```
`Intent i = new Intent("your first activity".this , "your 2nd activity class".class);
i.putExtra("id_variable", "id_value");
startactivity(i);`
```

2) now coming to your 2nd activity...
 -get data from 1st activity
 -if you are using AsyncTask class you can get data from 1st intent in onPreExecute method (it will run first)
 - than in onPostExecute you can have data from db(using api or anything else)
 - than simply call that class in you onCreate() method. :)

Hope that Helps.... :)

Edit:
onCreate will be called for sure... onResume will be called when your app turns into background and returns... onPause will be called when your app is in background....

Comment: i dont use asynctask in secind activity !

Comment: im calling this activity Frequently and im not sure about onCreate

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: how many an activity will be created ? imagine a user call this with a btn and back by press back btn , and call it again ! this activity created again ?

Comment: every time you coming to your 2nd activity... onCreate will be called.

Comment: and what about onStart() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for