# Android Fragment not loaded when open the application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to android. I am trying to develop an app using android fragments.
Initially it works nicely.Once i close and reopen the app means fragment not loaded. If anyone knows please let me.

i tried following code

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    MapFragment llf = new MapFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.id_new_map, llf);
    ft.commit();
```

but not working.

Comment: You execute that piece of code inside the onCreate()? Do you check some condition? Or just always execute it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mimmo is directing ... you probably will want to move the code to `onResume()`.

Also, you should use the Fragment Manager, something like below.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_alphabet_layout, new MapFragment(), getResources(R.id.id_new_map));
fragmentTransaction.commit();
boolean wereThereWereAnyPendingTransactions = fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: I should add that you should familiarize yourself with the lifecycle by using the diagram show on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for