# Why should the "Parse" Object be declared inside the "onCreate" method?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm using [parse.com](/questions/tagged/parse.com) as a backend for my Android app. One thing that bothered me when i was writing the code is

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
}
```

Why should you declare the parseobject in `onCreate()` method?
Can we declare a `ParseObject` inside the main method that looks something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
}
```

If i do this the class is not getting created in the backend. So, I'm looking for a specific reason why `ParseObject` needs to be created inside `onCreate()` method?

Comment: `main` method is not called by android unlike java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) programming, not [java](/questions/tagged/java) – if you declare the function `main(String[] args)` it does not get called.

You have to respect the lifecycle of `Application`, `Activity`, and `Fragment` classes. Typically `onCreate()` is the first method in the lifecycle that you can access.

In [parse.com](/questions/tagged/parse.com) you usually call `Parse.initialize()` within `Application.onCreate()` and then to all your actions like queries and object creation on your `Activities`/`Fragments`. If you download the [sample project](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) you can learn how to use Parse in an Android project.

Answer (score 1):

you have to mention the lifecycle of android applications. 
[Link to Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

As you can see, the main(String[]) method is not part of it like in java.

The onCreate() method is the first method that is called, 
so you should do data preparation and parsing in this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Android works: `onCreate` is going to be the first method the Operating System will call to create your Activity.

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html