# Starting Android app with onStart() method, not onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am new to android and I am learning android by creating various basic applications to clear my understanding. I have gone through android life cycle so I tried to write below codes.

**First one** is normal with **onCreate() method** and **Second one** is just created **with onStart()** method but **without onCreate()** method but still **both works properly** without any error.

My doubt: How application can start without onCreate() method with Activity as Superclass. Is it not wrong according to life cycle? (But still it is working !)

**First One:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91**********"));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Second One:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91**********"));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for) Take a look at this question, there are great explanations about each one and why you should start your views on onCreate and the activity lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How application can start without onCreate()...

Without being overridden, the *super Activity's* `onCreate()` will be called instead.

> Is it not wrong according to life cycle?

From the point of view of OOP, you did nothing wrong. But, from the point of view of `Activity's` lifecycle, not overriding the `onCreate()` method is not what "you're expected to do". You should stick to the lifecycle methods as per the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) or numerous posts on the Internet in order to manage Activity's states properly.

For instance, in your case you're making a call from improper `Activity's` state, unless you intended to do so. According to the `Activity's` lifecycle the `onCreate()` method is called just once, - on *Activity* instance creation, while the `onStart()` method may be called multiple times during its lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `OnCreate` it doesn't mean that this method is not invoked - you just don't have it overrided.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the `onStart()` will be triggered *everytime* the app triggers the onRestart(), e.g when you take the activity out of visibility than take it back to visibility.

The `onCreate()` happens only once, when the activity is **created**, or when you **kill** the app then recreate it.

And the `onStart()` happens after the `onCreate()`, as you can see in [this lifeCycle](http://pds11.egloos.com/pds/200812/01/63/c0043363_49336ea62d4c6.jpg)