# What application operations should normally be implemented in Android Lifecycle Methods

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am newbie to **Android** development. I completely understand `Android Lifecycle` and how each `Lifecycle method`'s purpose is by reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for).

But what **code statements** (operations) should normally be implemented in each of these Lifecycle methods (`onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume` and so on).

For example, I found almost all of `UI interactions` operations are implemented in `onCreate` method. I mean linking UI Views by `findViewById` and define click event listeners on these views by `setOnClickListener`.

In this phenomenon, what kind of operations are normally done in other `Lifecycle methods`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be something like:

**onCreate:**

- `findViewById` lookups
- Setup views listeners
- Open database connections
- Initialize third party libraries
- Initialize [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)
- Open files

**onStart:**

- Open remote resources
- Register [BroadcastReceivers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

**onResume:**

- Initialize animations

**onPause:**

- Get ready to save variables in the [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) bundle
- Start clearing resources if [isFinishing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) is true.

**onStop:**

- Unregister BroadcastReceivers
- Close cursors
- Close remote resources
- Close files
- Clear heavy references (Bitmaps/Videos)
- Clear [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) cache
- Release [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) references.

**onDestroy:**

- Clear references to everything else (wouldn't be called in some cases)

Comment: There is an `onSaveInstanceState` method that replaces your use case for `onPause`

Comment: Yes, that's the callback I'm actually referring to.