# Activity crash lifecycle method - android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, crash, backup

I'm developing an app which in a case of crash, needs to save some data with the time of the crash. Now, I'm saving the data in onDestroy() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    saveState();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But whenever I crash my app on purpose, onDestroy() is not called and my data is not saved.

My question is, how can I save my data on a crash? Which approach should I take?
Because I need the time of the crash to be also saved, it's mandatory.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/3981656

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) is perfect for catching crashes.

Comment: I implemented this handler in my code and it works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't detect sudden crashes through `onDestroy` or `onStop` methods. Your options are:

1. Use try-catch blocks. Wrap up the probable places of crash in try block and catch the exceptions in the catch block, then you can gracefully close the app.
2. Implement try-catch blocks at susceptible placecs. Then, you can integrate [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) to your app and log the exceptions  to crashlytics in the catch block. Let the app used thoroughly by a couple of users and then at crashlytics analytics, you can see the places where the app is actually crashing most of the times.
3. Use [acra](http://www.acra.ch/). It catches exceptions, retrieves lots of context data and send them to the backend of your choice.

You can always record the system time in the catch block and save your data there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try to implement this and update my post