# Native Android: Invoke notification when application crash

Tags: java, android

I would like my app to notify the user if the application has crashed.

build.gradle(:app)

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Things I did:
invoking `createNotificationChannel()` on `onCreate()`
calling `createNotification()` on `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

createNotification() and createNotificationChannel()

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Notification.Builder createNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "screenomics_id")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.switch_thumb)
                .setContentTitle("Screenomics app has stopped!")
                .setContentText("If this is unintentional, please restart the application.")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return builder;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "screenomics";
            String description = "screenomics description";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("screenomics_id", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

onDestroy()

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(0, createNotification().build());
        }
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

onStop()

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            try {
                stopRecording();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.notify(0, createNotification().build());
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: When an app crashes it already too late to run any code in your app. You'll have to capture the Error/Exception, but you should program your app so that it doesn't happen. See: [Activity crash lifecycle method - android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38349219/295004)

Comment: This may sound weird but my logcat does not show where the error is. My application is expected to run in the background on interval and after some (200-500) iterations, it will suddenly stop without proper warning logcat. 

I suscept it might be because of RAM issue as it would fire (xx frames skipped...) whenever I run the app and everytime I open the app, the frame skipped increase. Is there a way to detect this?

Comment: I suspect its "My application is expected to run in the background on interval" and either you are doing something or the Android framework is. You would do better with a new question with details as to how you are running in the background (OS version, how testing - device/emulator, how does the service work, doze mode etc.) given that a number of iterations do work. I would check if you have a service memory or service connection leak.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your advice. Thanks!