# How the setcontentview is called?

Tags: java, android

I was tweaking the sample hello world app that android studio provides and found out that I cannot call the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` outside any method.For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //compilation error
}
```

I know that I should not be calling `setContentView` outside `onCreate()`,but just for a reference I tried it out.I can figure out that this has something to do with Java and not android,but I can't seem to figure out the where the problem exactly lies.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It needs to be **inside** the `onCreate()` method, not **outside**.

Comment: The compilation error is because a call to a method has to be inside another method, a static block or used in an expression (for example to initialize a variable).

Comment: It needs to be called inside any method and It will set the content view with no problem. You must read OOP fundamentals.

Comment: Just move the first closing bracket (`}`) **one line down**. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

As per [activity life cycle](https://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjdwJiXmOLPAhUHKo8KHfGPCuAQFgghMAY&sig2=W488XRAET6WykOPKIvGNKQ&usg=AFQjCNEppv0ASqUl76q4lEyFotBzQ0JCAg) `onCreate()` is the method called when the activity is first created

OnCreate() is the point where most initialization should go: calling `setContentView(int)` to inflate the activity's UI, using `findViewById` to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI, calling managedQuery(android.net.Uri , String[], String, String[], String) to