# Android activity life cycle-what is onPreCreate() function for?

Tags: android, android-activity, mobile

I downloaded signal open source sms app from https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android on main activity there is overrided function **onPreCreate()** can anybody explain to me what does it do as this function is not included in the activity life cycle as explained in this link [Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for).

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a method they define in their abstract base `Activity` classes. It's not part of the standard `Activity` lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

@Nofi, my only experience with onPreCreate() is when using AsyncTasks. Perhaps it's a bit of code that needs to be run before the actual onCreate() method in order to secure whatever happens during the actual activity.