# ImageView nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am trying to move an ImageView whilst the user touches the screen. I originally tried a while loop from an onTouchEvent method but this halted some background processes that I needed. I now have a thread that I use to control my game which involves a call to update my ImageView's position based on a float called 'movementSpeed' which is determined by Motion events. The issue, I believe, is with the initialization of my ImageView but I have tried many solutions from other questions which don't seem to work for me.
I considered whether this would be because I was calling the method from a Thread and tried running the method on the UI thread but it still did not work. However, I have discovered that the position will be updated if I call updateCharPos from my touch event method, although this would cause the aforementioned difficulty in carrying out other tasks.

Activity Java:

```
package fozard.backuptestapp;


public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {

private GameThread thread;
private float charX=0;
ImageView character;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    character = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.character);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    thread=new GameThread();
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            thread.setMovementSpeed(5);
            thread.setMoving(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            thread.setMoving(false);
    }
    return true;
}

public void updateCharPos(float movementSpeed){
    Log.d("Updating", "Should be able to update");
    charX = character.getX();
    System.out.print(charX);
}
}
```

Thread code:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {

public static final int maxFps=30;
private double averageFps;
private boolean isRunning;
private int score=0;
private Play play = new Play();
private boolean isMoving;
private float movementSpeed=0;


public void setMovementSpeed(float movementSpeed){
    this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
}

public void setMoving(Boolean isMoving){
    this.isMoving = isMoving;
}

public void setRunning(Boolean isRunning){
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
}


@Override
public void run(){
    long startTime;
    long timeMillis;
    long waitTime;
    int frameCount=0;
    long totalTime=0;
    long targetTime= 1000/maxFps;

    while (isRunning){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        timeMillis = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
        waitTime = targetTime-timeMillis;
        try{
            if (waitTime>0){
                currentThread().sleep(waitTime);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        frameCount++;
        score=score+1;
        if (isMoving){
                try{
                    update();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                }
        }

        if (frameCount==maxFps){
            averageFps=1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
            frameCount=0;
            totalTime=0;
            System.out.println(averageFps);
        }
    }
}

public void update(){
    play.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            play.updateCharPos(movementSpeed);
        }
    });

   }
}
```

and my stack trace:

```
11-23 19:46:51.715 27465-27504/fozard.backuptestapp I/System.out: 30.0
11-23 19:46:52.710 27465-27504/fozard.backuptestapp I/System.out: 30.0
11-23 19:46:53.705 27465-27504/fozard.backuptestapp I/System.out: 30.0
11-23 19:46:54.105 27465-27465/fozard.backuptestapp D/Updating: Should be able to update
11-23 19:46:54.105 27465-27465/fozard.backuptestapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-23 19:46:54.105 27465-27465/fozard.backuptestapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d29700)
11-23 19:46:54.125 27465-27465/fozard.backuptestapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1914)
                                                                      at fozard.backuptestapp.Play.updateCharPos(Play.java:55)
                                                                      at fozard.backuptestapp.GameThread$1.run(GameThread.java:88)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 19:46:54.840 27465-27504/fozard.backuptestapp I/System.out: 30.0
11-23 19:46:55.835 27465-27504/fozard.backuptestapp I/System.out: 30.0
```

any help would be appreciated!

Xml:

```
ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/character"
    android:id="@+id/character"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false" /
```

Comment: Are you sure R.id.character is pointing to an ImageView?  Can you post your activity_play layout?

Comment: @mWhitley .  from my activity_play layout:  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/character"
        android:id="@+id/character"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false" /> I believe that this is correct? Also if I call the updateCharPos() method from the onTouchEvent method it will update the position but causes an issue with other tasks (above)

Comment: @BFozard can you post your layout code (xml)?

Comment: @HenriqueMS I've added it now

Comment: @BFozard I was hoping for the complete R.layout.activity_play file that you are inflating ;)

Comment: `Play play = new Play();`  you are not allowed to create activities yourself. Use the activity that was started by android instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I had not noticed but like @njzk2 wrote in the comments you are manually instantiating a class that extends `Activity` which explains the strange behaviour I was talking about

```
private Play play = new Play();
```

`Activity`'s subclasses should not be directly instantiated, right [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) is a good tutorial in this.

If you are doing this from inside Activity you can:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NAME_OF_NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Your actual call flow goes like this :

```
Play (Activity) -> new GameThread() -> new Play() (Activity) -> new GameThread()
```

It's probably not what you want right?

Moreover, if you are starting an Activity from another thread, you need to have a Context so you can launch the new activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, Play.class);

mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

The fact that you are getting the NPE directly in the `findViewById()` call makes me think that you may not yet have the activity fully created which is strange.

For further debugging can you substitute

```
character = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.character);
```

for

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    //breakpoint here, check if you have the mInflater
    View layoutView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_play, null);

    //breakpoint here, check if you have the layoutView
    ImageView character = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.character);

    //if you get here you should be in the clear
    setContentView(layoutView);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You and @njzk2 were right about it being caused by creating a new instance of the activity. I ended up using 'public static Play play' within the activity and 'play=this;' within onCreate(). This allowed me to reference the existing instance of the activity from the thread by 'Play.play.updateCharPos(movementSpeed);' and it now works perfectly! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @BFozard just be careful with that ideia, by keeping the static reference to the Activity there is a high probability that you are keeping it from being garbage collected, therefore leaking memory. I would advise you to use Activities according to Android patterns. I'm glad I could help cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `R.id.character` actually references a valid view, you may want to move the background thread initialization `thread=new GameThread();` to either the `onStart()` or `onResume()` function to guarantee that the required UI components are actually present.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/1525953) for more details about the Android Lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Boo. I've checked that R.id.character does reference a valid view and tried the following ammendment: '@Override'
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        thread=new GameThread();
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }          but the issue still occurs. The weird part is that if i call the updateCharPos from the touch event it works (although this causes the original issue with halting other processes)