# hi, looking to allow app to keep runing in background so i can use the phone

Tags: android

i made an online streaming radio app, very simple, my only problem is when i click the home button it stops.

i just wanted to know if someone can help me with the code on how to make my radio play in background so people can use the phone while they listen to the station.

and (if possible to be pointed out to) how can i add it to the drop down notification with the pause and stop button like you-tube and tune-in radio does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a Service, those are designed to run in background.
Also use the Notification to have buttons.