# How stop the sound sounds when I close the app

Tags: java, android, audio, background, media-player

I can  not stop the sound/ sounds when I close the app.or press the back button. Sound is playin in background and not any widget to stop sound so these are  my codes. how to fix it isue. and what I need?
 Thanks :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   MediaPlayer s1;  Button agackakan;
   MediaPlayer s2;  Button getCam_bastankarasi;



  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);



        s1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,ormann_agackakani_taklama);
        s2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cam_bastankarasi);


    agackakan=(Button) findViewById ( R.id.agackakan);
    getCam_bastankarasi= (Button) findViewById (R.id.cambastankarasi);


    agackakan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            s1.start();

        }   });   

    getCam_bastankarasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            s2.start();

        }   });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to override the `onPause()`  of the activity

write this code in your activity class...

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
       super.onPause();
       if(s1.isPlaying()){
            s1.stop();
            s1.release();
            }
       if(s2.isPlaying()){
            s2.stop();
            s2.release();
            }
    }
```

Comment: `How stop the sound sounds when I close the app` i think need to override `onDestroy()`

Comment: but doesn't before onDestroy()  onStop()  will be called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for here it is said When you click the back button OR try to finish() the activity the events are called as below:

onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()

Comment: onPause() should also be called before onStop(), so you should only need the code in one of those two lifecycle methods, depending on the behavior you want (if you want the music to stop when the activity is partially covered, such as if a dialog comes up, then do it onPause)

Comment: I did not add on code can you show on code please I m new

Comment: if  20+ sounds have ? how we add on code? I have 32 sounds file :)

Comment: is it possible Stop MediaPlayer ? if possible this is the fast way.

Comment: oh nic to hear :) how?

Comment: Where to add your code from?  I try a way but not worked

Comment: add the code after you close your oncreate() { ...}  block in the MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

To mute **MediaPlayer** when your application is sent to background, you can call this code on `onPause()` or `onStop()` on every activity in your application:

```
public static void muteIfSentToBackground(final Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            if(s1 != null){
                s1.stop();
                s1.release();
                s1 =null;
            }
            if(s2 != null){
                s2.stop();
                s2.release();
                s2 = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        muteIfSentToBackground(this);}

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
            muteIfSentToBackground(this);}
```

Comment: I did not add on code can you show on code please I m new