# Is Android app visible during onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I plan on checking login status of a user in `onCreate` of `MainActivity` - and if the user is logged in - immediately redirect to some other View (e.g. `ProfileActivity`)

I am worried that `MainActivity` will flicker into the users view before disappearing. Is this of any concern?

Comment: No Activity is not visible during onCreate. It gets visible after onResume() of an acitivty.

Comment: I believe not as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Comment: Just create something like StartupActivity without view and launch any activity you want from there based on conditions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep `MainActivity` as `LAUNCHER` (on `singleTask` mode) and check the login status before you pass layout to it. This approach will avoid logged in users to wait for 2nd Activity to be launched.

Note that in @Nicola De Fiorenze answer Activity instance will get killed in all cases. Hence you will create 2 instances of Activity even for users who have already passed login phase.

Code may look like this:

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(!AuthUtils.isLoggedIn()){
        LoginActivity.startActivity(this);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // Once you know user is logged in, pass layout to activity
    setContentView(resLayoutId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an invisible activity as the main activity.

Inside you can place some logic which determines which activity to show to the user first.

Manifest Declaration, with noHistory="true"

```
<activity
    android:name=".LandingActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

LandingActivity class:

```
public class LandingActivity extends Activity { 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    Class<?> firstActivityClass; 
    try{ 
        String className = getFirtsActivityClassName(); 
        firstActivity = Class.forName(className); 
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        firtsActivity = MainActivity.class; 
    } 
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), firstActivity); 
    startActivity(intent); 

    finish(); 
} 

private String getFirtActivityClassName() {       
    // Here the logic 
} 

}
```

Comment: This is generally not a good solution as user will spend seconds waiting for activity to launch. If you plan to use this approach at least try the splash pattern as it let user know what is happening and why he has to wait..

Answer (score 0):

It's not **Resumed** or **Started** but you can **do** the action you want.. When `Activity` is getting created you are **allowed** to do any action that alter the activity **state** as it is NOT **Stopped** or **Paused**!

For example you can attach a `fragment` or change a view if you like!