# How to remove listener from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For receiving data from Firebase Realtime Database I need to register listener:

```
objectReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

What is correct way to remove (unregister) this listener?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way to remove a listener is to remove it accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity using this line of code:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Note that, if you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.

But remember `onDestroy` is not always called.

Edit:

The above `databaseReference` object can be any object of type [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). For instance, if you are listening to real-time updates to a node called users:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
```

The code to remove the lister should look like this:

```
usersRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

And here is the correct import:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. I was confused a little because names of adding and removing functions are not consistent.

Comment: You can see here on info about activity life cycle : and when to add and destroy based on your needs : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299029/3904109

Comment: removeEventListener deprecated? I don't have this option for FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(myPath)

Comment: @Dpedrinha The [removeEventListener(ValueEventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) method exists inside the [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) class, and it's **not** deprecated.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please edit your answer and add the code to get databaseReference? Because my databaseReference doesn't show the removeEventListener option. What am I missing?

Comment: @Dpedrinha Please check my updated answer. Don't also forget to add the correct import.

Comment: @AlexMamo It seems I'm using the wrong import then. My code is exactly the same and it doesn't autocomplete removeEventListener. Can you please add your import to the answer?

Comment: @Dpedrinha Sure, please check my updated answer. Please also make sure to have the correct dependency added.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to check whether listener is null or has an object, because if the listener object is null there will be a runtime error

```
if(valueEventListener!=null){
  databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: Where should you call this. Im new to Android and was wondering, should it be in `onDestroy` method!?

Comment: it depends on the code. in my case i remove it in `onBackPressed` overrided method in the Activity.  or in `onDestroy()` is also fine

Comment: Again being new, can I put it in both methods? I forget that android has the back button, Im an iPhone user.

Comment: Yes you should try it

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it like this:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    firebase.database().ref('example').child(this.state.somethingDyamic).off('value');
  };

  doSomething() {
    firebase.database().ref('example').child(this.state.somethingDyamic).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      ...
   });
  }
```

Comment: What if the state changes in the lifecycle of the component? Then a different child will be unbound..