# Android:What will happen if onResume method is not called on android activity?

Tags: java, android, onresume

For example, I have an activity named `MyActivity` and it doesn't have the function `onResume()`.

So basically what would happen if I resume the activity? Will it call the `onCreate()` method or something else?

Comment: doesn't need to override this method, its handled by activity life cycle.

Comment: onResume is the default life cyle method. this will help you to understand.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Comment: Extended class Activity is already having onResume function. Hope you understand abstract class concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you didn't write the delegate methods like onResume(), onDestroy(), onPause etc.. those standard life cycle methods will meet all the times when you do the respected activity in the screen.

Whenever you need some functionality to be executed in specific delegate then you would need to override the method in your activity screen java file and put your functionality related code inside the overrided method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer now I got it!!! @Bethan

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how the activity life cycle goes.

**When you first open the activity A**

onCreate is called ====> OnStart is called ====> OnResume is called.

**When you return to the activity A** (FROM A BACK PRESS).

OnStart is called ====> OnResume is called.

**Conclusion**

If you don't have (on resume) or (on start) implemented then nothing will happen **on create won't be called when your activity is resumed**.

If you want to call something when your activity is revisited (from a back press), you must implement your code in (onstart) or (onresume). Because (onCreate) is ignored on activity resumes.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is one of the methods called throughout the activity lifecycle. onResume() is the counterpart to `onPause()` which is called anytime an activity is hidden from view, e.g. if you start a new activity that hides it. `onResume()` is called when the activity that was hidden comes back to view on the screen.