# Position of super-class method implementation with android studio

Tags: android

Well, latest question I posted was my first post, so I admit I didn't summarize my question well . So I am going to ask a question again.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)         
}
```

I know onCreate() method in superclass(AppCompactActivity) create Activity before starting it. Then, isn't it necessary for "super.onCreate" to come before the initialization of View(like setConentView)?? But, When I put the superclass method implementation in the far below, it didn't make problem (code working normally), Why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to call `onCreate` first because major chunk of initialization already happens in the constructor of the Activity. `onCreate` method is provided to the developer to do any app specific initialization.

If you look at the internals of `onCreate`, it does bunch of stuffs like set the action bar, initialize fragments, apply the theme and other support library related stuffs but the parent view of the activity (called decor view) is already initialized. By calling `setContentView` we are just inflating the passed layout id and setting it as a child of decor view.

Try running the application without calling `setContentView`. The application will flawlessly run with the action bar on top but you won't see any view added.

To summarize, `super.onCreate` and `setContentView` are two independent operations.

Comment: So you mean function of onCreate in superclass is just adding a titlebar and actionbar (in this case, set the parent view???)???

Comment: ah.. but I can't understand exactly. if the function of onCreate in superclass is set parent view, isn't it necessary it comes before any other inflation of view? because we need parent view first to inflate the child view

Comment: we can say that parent view is inflated (or created) even before Activity's `onCreate` is called.

Comment: well, if parent view is inflated before the call of overrided onCreate, what  is the exact function of  'super.onCreate(...)' ??

Comment: I have edited my answer, actually it does bunch of other stuffs. But the point being the initialization of the parent view take place before `onCreate` is called. That's why you can call `setContentView` after `onCreate`, since both are independent calls.

Comment: hmm so.. you mean it is a rule that order of "which place super.onCreate() come " is not important but at least we need the code inside the overrided onCreate for the method working??

Comment: ]I have understood that super.onCreate create Activity. But If it does, I thought super.onCreate() code had to come the top of the inside of overrided onCreated

Comment: Since some of the activity creation happens before `onCreate` is called. We can say that by calling `super.onCreate`, remaining part of activity creation is being executed.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think there are much more things for me to learn.. Anyway, I 'm glad to have enough question and appreciate your  sincere Help.!!!!!!

Comment: + Can you tell me Which part I have to refer to get specific things?? Activity LifeCycle??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. Do you want to learn about activity lifecycle?

Comment: For the starters, following explains very well about activity lifecycle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for