# fragment lifecycle when activity stopped

Tags: android-activity, fragment, lifecycle

When activity is moved to "stopped" state,then what will happen to the life cycle of a "fragment" which is in that activity?

Comment: Do search and then [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for).Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Fragment **onStop()** method called, when activity is moved to stopped state. For more go through this link & understand fragment and activity states: 
https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/content/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-1-fragments/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications.html