# What happens to old activity after starting a new intent?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

what happens to the rest of the code of older activity after starting a new activity? here 'doSomeWork()' is called or not? does startActivity() work as a return statement?

```
public void method(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    doSomeWork();
}
```

Comment: You might want to view this question regarding Action Lifecycle Events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here 'doSomeWork()' is called or not?

It will be called immediately. `startActivity()` is not a blocking call. `newactivity` will not be started by the time `startActivity()` returns.

> does startActivity() work as a return statement?

No.