# Android: Meaning of "running in the foreground"?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

From the Android Developer documentation:

"When the activity enters the Resumed state, it comes to the foreground, and then the system invokes the onResume() callback."

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

**What means "comes to the foreground"?** Respectively: What's the opposite of running in the foreground?

Comment: It means that it becomes active and ready for user interaction. have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Running in the Foreground** means your app is currently **Fully Visible** on your device, you can see it and interact with it and it will respond to you right away.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **"comes to the foreground"** means, as Sam Chen said, your app is fully visible. Normally in fullscreen, so the user can interact with your app.

The callback **onResume()** is called, when your app was running in the background and is now coming to the foreground again (e.g. the user was using your app, switched to another one and then comes back to your app).

You might use this callback to do certain things to e.g. reload the current content to be up-to-date.