# Activity Life Cycle: How can a new activtiy come to the foreground before being created?

Tags: android, events, android-activity, oncreate, onpause

While reading a couple of answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for?noredirect=1&lq=1), the following passage from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/15312420) had me in a state of confusion:

> `onPause()`:
> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to onResume(). When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.

The above seems to suggest the following ordering of events:

1. B is launched *in front* of A;
2. `onPause()` is called on A;
3. `onPause()` returns;
4. B is created.

What I don't understand pertains to how can the first event precede the fourth, i.e., how can B be launched and *appear* ***in front*** of A before being created in the first place.

Comment: A better phrasing of the confusing sentence might be: "When activity B is *requested to be* launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A".

Comment: @CommonsWare So actually `onPause()` is called on A before B appears in the foreground?

Comment: To be honest, I have not tried checking at that level in many years. You might want to run your own experiments! I am simply used to how Google tends to write their documentation and how to try to "patch up" confusing phrasing.

Comment: 1- You request to launch B. 2- B is not launched yet and not visible too.  3- `onPause` of A is called. 4- `onPause` is finished 5- B is now launched and visible.

Comment: To get the idea you can add some logs to Both A and B lifecycle methods like `onCreate`, `onStart`, ...  to see the order of calling these methods.