# Why is there an extra onPause onResume when launching action call?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have a simple setup that launches the dialer to make a call using `ACTION_CALL`

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_dialer)
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate")
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_launch).setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "Launching Call")
            val uri = Uri.parse("tel:3332223333")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("TAG", "onResume")
    }
    
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("TAG", "onPause")
    }
```

I'm logging each lifecycle and seeing weird behavior.  There seems to be an extra `onPause` `onResume` once the user clicks the launch button.

I get the following log output when clicking the launch button above.

```
Launching Call
onPause
onResume <-- This is unexpected
onPause
onStop
```

I am unable to figure out why the lifecycle transitions back to `onResume` after the initial `onPause`.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Additional context:
I'm trying to do some work in `onPause` but it is getting duplicated because of the unexpected `onResume` call

Comment: Is there an orientation change occurring when you launch the call? Maybe your app is in landscape mode and the phone app is portrait?

Comment: No, there is no orientation change, I've double-checked.  Also launching any other activity does not cause this behavior. It seems to be just the call intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid to call onResume() when back within App. Because Activity lifecycle Working with this behaviour. I think, this link will help you

> [Android activity life cycle - what are all these methods for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for)